# Links for AES 128 bit CFB Implemenation or sample application

Tags: encryption, aes

Does anybody know sample application or link where i can test 128 bit AES CFB implemenation given a password and some data.

Thanks

Comment: Hi,ckv. Did u get sample code of AES-128 CFB encryption? Please share that code.  I am also stuck there. I have done lots of googling.

Comment: Actually i used a DLL provided by a 3rd party for performing the AES 128 CFB Encryption. So i didnt actually implement the algorithm. SO unfortunately i dont have what you are asking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A number of crypto libraries support AES in CFB mode, including:

- [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) [C]
- [Crypto++](http://www.cryptopp.com/) [C++]
- [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net) [C++]
- [PyCrypto](http://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) [Python]
- [BouncyCastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/) [C# / Java]

Any one of these would probably work; most will come with test vectors (which NIST also makes available as caf mentions and links to), and you can of course also write a program to test a specific set of inputs if this is desirable.

Answer (score 1):

Does http://www.hanewin.net/encrypt/aes/aes-test.htm work for you?

Comment: i specifically want CFB mode implementation

Answer (score 1):

The [NIST AES test vectors](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/aes/KAT_AES.zip) include CFB tests.